# How to remove rows which have max 2 value of each column and make the left dataframe as long as possible?

Tags: r

I want to remove the max `2` value(outliers) of each column and then analyze the left dataframe.

```
> data.frame(q1 = c(2, 4, 5,8,8), q2 = c(1, 6, 3,8,5), q3 = c(5, 3, 6,5,2))
  q1 q2 q3
1  2  1  5
2  4  6  3
3  5  3  6
4  8  8  5
5  8  5  2
```

The max 2 value in `q1`:8,8,then row 5,4 should be removed
The max 2 value in `q2`:8,6,then row 4,2 should be removed
The max 2 value in `q3`:6,5,then row 3,4(**not 1**,to keep the left dataframe as long as possible,which means remove rows as less as possible) should be removed

The expect result as below:

```
  q1 q2 q3
1  2  1  5
```

How to do it?

Comment: Be aware that ***"keep the left dataframe as long as possible"*** makes this an optimization problem for which simple approaches will not guarantee best solutions as the number of rows and columns grows.

Comment: @Shree,yes,that's why I ask here

Comment: What is the size of your actual dataframe?

Comment: @Shree,50 columns,2000 rows

Answer (score 1):

The two or `n` maxima in each vector column are found with an auxiliary function `max2vals`. The function is `lapply`ed to the dataframe and the corresponding rows are removed.

```
max2vals <- function(x, n = 2){
  tail(order(x), n)
}


df1 <- data.frame(q1 = c(2, 4, 5,8,8), 
                  q2 = c(1, 6, 3,8,5), 
                  q3 = c(5, 3, 6,5,2))

i <- unique(unlist(lapply(df1, max2vals)))
df1[-i,, drop = FALSE]
#  q1 q2 q3
#1  2  1  5
```

Comment: It is just a co-incidence here that `order` returns the same output as OP's expected output. Try this on `df1 <- data.frame(q1 = c(8, 4, 5,1,2), 
                  q2 = c(8, 6, 3,8,8), 
                  q3 = c(5, 3, 6,5,2))` here for column 2 to `remove rows as less as possible` we need to select row 1 with either 4 or 5 but it removes row 4 and 5 for column 2.

Comment: Agree with @RonakShah. However I don't think there would be any simpler solution as the possible combinations to check will grow pretty quickly depending on size of actual dataframe. A greedy approach might just be reasonably simple although it doesn't guarantee optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `<<-` (which only will affect function environment) to generate a vector `rem` that contains the rows to be removed from `d`. Every iteration takes a lookup* if the rows to be removed already exist in `rem` and takes the combination with the best value.

```
rmfun <- function(d) {
  rem <- NA
  return(d[-unlist(sapply(d, function(i) {
    cb <- combn(seq(i), 2, simplify=FALSE)  # all combn of rows
    mx <- sapply(cb, function(cb) sum(i[cb]))  # sums of combn
    wm <- which(mx == max(mx))  # max combn
    wm <- wm[which.max(colSums(sapply(wm, function(wm) cb[[wm]] %in% rem)))]  # lookup*
    rem <<- na.omit(c(rem, cb[[wm]]))
  })), ])
}
```

#### Test data frames

```
d1
#   q1 q2 q3
# 1  2  1  5
# 2  4  6  3
# 3  5  3  6
# 4  8  8  5
# 5  8  5  2

d2
#   q1 q2 q3
# 1  8  8  5
# 2  4  6  3
# 3  5  3  6
# 4  1  8  5
# 5  2  8  2
```

#### Result

```
rmfun(d1)
#   q1 q2 q3
# 1  2  1  5

rmfun(d2)
#   q1 q2 q3
# 2  4  6  3
# 5  2  8  2
```

#### Data

```
d1 <- structure(list(q1 = c(2, 4, 5, 8, 8), q2 = c(1, 6, 3, 8, 5), 
    q3 = c(5, 3, 6, 5, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
d2 <- structure(list(q1 = c(8, 4, 5, 1, 2), q2 = c(8, 6, 3, 8, 8), 
    q3 = c(5, 3, 6, 5, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: If I only remove the max one,change function with `combn(seq(i), 1, simplify=FALSE)`,`rmfun(d1)` will get error `'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer I think the question deserves but probably not the one it needs (Batman?!).

This is a mixed integer programming (MIP) approach using `ompr` for mathematical modeling and `glpk` as solver. I have included the step-by-step logic in the code comments.

Note that both `ompr` and `gplk` were too slow for `2000 x 50` dataset. @jay.sf solution took 5 minutes for the same dataset but it did easily run out of memory when I tried to remove top 3 per column so does have its limitations.

**My suggestion** - If optimality is important, investigate MIP options (try python as well) otherwise @jay.sf solution with small `n` should be good enough.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ROI)
library(ROI.plugin.glpk)
library(ompr)
library(ompr.roi)

remove_rows <- function(df, n = 2) {
  # mark top n values in every column
  df_logical <- df %>% 
    mutate_all(~. %in% sort(., decreasing = T)[1:n])

  # marks which rows are removable i.e any row with at least one 1 in it
  xij_bounds <- as.matrix(unname(+df_logical))

  a <- nrow(df) # number of rows
  b <- ncol(df) # number of columns

  MIPModel() %>%
    # x[i,j] is 1 when cell i,j is selected for removal else 0
    add_variable(x[i,j], i = 1:a, j = 1:b, type = "binary") %>%
    # y[i] is 1 when row i is selected for removal else 0
    add_variable(y[i], i = 1:a, type = "binary") %>% 
    # objective is minimize number of removed rows
    set_objective(sum_expr(y[i], i = 1:a), "min") %>%
    # y[i] = 1 when any x[i,j] = 1 for any i
    add_constraint(y[i] - x[i,j] >= 0, i = 1:a, j = 1:b) %>% 
    # at least remove n values from every column j
    add_constraint(sum_expr(x[i,j], i = 1:a) >= n, j = 1:b) %>%
    # x[i,j] can be 1 only when cell i,j belongs to top n values of column j
    add_constraint(x[i,j] - xij_bounds[i,j] <= 0, i = 1:a, j = 1:b) %>% 
    # solve model
    solve_model(with_ROI(solver = "glpk")) %>% 
    # get indices of rows to remove i.e. where y[i] = 1
    get_solution(y[i]) %>% 
    filter(value > 0) %>% 
    pull(i)
}
```

#### Example 1 -

```
df1
  q1 q2 q3
1  2  1  5
2  4  6  3
3  5  3  6
4  8  8  5
5  8  5  2

remove_rows(df1)
[1] 2 3 4 5

df1[-remove_rows(df1), ]
  q1 q2 q3
1  2  1  5
```

#### Example 2 -

```
df2
  q1 q2 q3
1  8  8  5
2  4  6  3
3  5  3  6
4  1  8  5
5  2  8  2

remove_rows(df2)
[1] 1 3 4

df2[-remove_rows(df2), ]
  q1 q2 q3
2  4  6  3
5  2  8  2
```

#### Example 3 -

```
# Based on your comment I tried with below dataframe of dim 2000x50
set.seed(2)
df3 <- data.frame(replicate(50, sample(2000)))

# Both, ompr modeling and glpk solver, are too slow for my liking

# checking time with @jay.sf solution for top 2
system.time(result <- rmfun(df3, n = 2))
   user  system elapsed 
 298.90    0.01  300.24 

# it runs out of memory for top 3
system.time(result <- rmfun(df3, n = 3))
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 9.9 Gb
```